# how to load vuejs component from laravel blade?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2

I'have multiple auth laravel dashboard. When i login the default page redirect me to the client dashboard blade. When i write something in client blade.It does not show anything.I am using vuejs routers. Everything is working perfect. I tried to call component in that blade but it's still showing blank .I want to redirect to dashboard component.

Controller:
I tried it with the return url('url here') but still not working for me.

```
public function index()
    {
        return view('client');
    }
```

Client Blade:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')

    <template>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <client_details></client_details>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>

        import clientdetails_header from "./clientdetails_header.vue";

        export default {

            data() {

                return {
                }
            },
            components: {
                'client_details': clientdetails_header
            },

            mounted() {
                console.log('Component mounted.')
            }
        }
    </script>

@endsection
```

Master Blade:

```
<ul>
  <li>
        <router-link to="/clientdashboard" title="dashboard">
         <span class="nav-link-text"><iclass="fal fa-user"></i>DashBoard</span>
        </router-link>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="page-wrapper" id="app">
    <div class="page-content">
         <router-view>
         </router-view>
    </div>
</div>
```

App.js

```
let routes = [
    {path: '/clientdashboard', component: require('./components/clientdashboard.vue').default},
]

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,

});

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    routes 
})
```

ClientHeader:

```
<template>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-12">
                <!-- Collapse -->
                <div id="panel-6" class="panel">
                    <div class="panel-hdr">
                        <h2>
                            Client Details
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-container show">
                        <div class="panel-content">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <span><b>Company name:</b></span> <br>
                                    <span><b>Company ABN:</b></span> <br>
                                    <span><b>Company address:</b></span> <br>
                                    <span><b>Company phone:</b></span> <br>
                                    <span><b>Company email:</b></span> <br>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <ul style="list-style: none;" class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                        <li style="text-decoration: none" v-for="todo in clientData">{{todo}}</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

        data() {
            return {
                user_id: this.$userId,
                clientData: {}
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getClientDetails() {

                axios.post(this.$path + 'api/getClientDetails', null,
                    {
                        params: {
                            'client_id': this.user_id,
                        }
                    })
                    .then(data => (
                        this.clientData = data.data));
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getClientDetails();
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: hmmm can you add the code of how you are instaciating Vue ?

Comment: @Eli okay,I have added component.

Comment: hmmmm... what I meant by instanciating is where you create you new Vue instance. do you at any point have a `new Vue` instanciation ?

Comment: That's in App.js file

Comment: ` el: '#app',` where is your app element ?

Comment: It's in master blade. I didn't put the full code because it's too long.

Comment: ok, sure I get it, just trying to figure out that you problem may be, so things not showing was something that could be a result of not starting the Vue instance correctly or not attaching the instance to an element, that is why I ask

Comment: So what's the solution now?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea trying to put Vue code directly inside blade.

I would suggest you create a `Client.vue` and put your code in it instead. Register it in your routes in app.js.

```
...
{path: '/client', component: require('./components/Client.vue')},
```

Then you can use the component in your Client blade.

```
<client></client>
```

I believe that would be a first step towards resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Load your app.js in `<head>` section of your blade.php

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" async></script>\
```

Also create a div with id app there.

```
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
</body>
```

Create App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss">
</style>
```

Go to resources/js/app.js file, you will see laravel already put code to instantiate vue in there. Register your route etc.

But for me, I create a new folder resources/js/vue, put all vue related files (components, routes, filters, vuex, mixins, directives) there, create index.js and moved the code to initiate vue inside index.js.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import components from './components'
import directives from './directives'
import mixins from './mixins'
import filters from './filters'

Vue.use(router)
Vue.use(store)
Vue.use(components)
Vue.use(directives)
Vue.use(mixins)
Vue.use(filters)

new Vue({ router, store, render: h => h(App) }).$mount('#app')

export default {}
```

resources/js/app.js

```
require('./vue')
// I also initiate service-worker, firebase, and other non vue related
// javascripts in this file
```